# Update count in row after Insert

Tags: postgresql

I'm completely new to SQL and have a question. I am using is PostgreSQL.

I have two tables called "employees" and "offices"

The table "employees" have a list of unique employees with each having an OfficeID (The office where they work).

What I want to do is to "count" the number of appearances of the Office_ID and take that count into the table "offices" where the "office_ID" have a column called "number_of_employees".

Being completely new to SQL the only thing I have managed to even come close to this is fore example.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE office_id = 203
```

But this only selects and gives the sum of rows with the id "203" that has to be manually entered into "number of empolyees"

What I want is a trigger function that updates the field "number_of_empolyees" when a new record is inserted into the table "empolyees"

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to store information in the database that can easily be derived from the existing data. Creating a view that returns the number of employees for each office would be the right thing to do

Comment: Hi, yes i understand that. But for this specific instance it is required. Creating the data manually by SELECT COUNT(*) opens up for "bad integrity" i guess. Thats why i want it generated by and automatic process.

Comment: I don't see how this could be "required". Actually I think it's the opposite:  tracking that count through a trigger opens up for  "bad integrity". A view **is** the right solution for this. The values in the view will always be correct. With a trigger you can't be certain.

Comment: Hi guys", thanks for your input. If creating a view fulfills the purpose of counting the appearances of each unique "office_ID" and showing "the count" in another table, that's fine. How do i proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is the way to go here.
I am assuming since you're completely new to SQL, you're unsure how to make it work (Edit: just seen your comment after posting :^D) .

The correct way to count employees for each office is:

```
SELECT office_id, COUNT(*) as employeeCount
FROM employees
GROUP BY office_id
```

Note how your `WHERE office_id = XXX` has been replaced by a `GROUP BY office_id` in order to count employees for all offices in a single query.

That being done, we can use it inside the view.
Be careful about the `JOIN`: I believe in your schema, an office may have no employee (for instance, right after you created it or right before you delete it). We will handle that part with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
CREATE VIEW OfficeWithEmployeeCount AS
SELECT Offices.*, EmployeeCount
FROM Offices
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT office_id, COUNT(*) as EmployeeCount FROM Employees GROUP BY office_id) T
    ON Offices.office_id = T.office_id
```

Note: to avoid having `NULL` returned in `EmployeeCount` for empty offices, you may want to write:

```
CREATE VIEW OfficeWithEmployeeCount AS
SELECT Offices.*, COALESCE(EmployeeCount,0)
FROM ...
```

Comment: Hi Lau. You are right i'm completely new to SQL and your answer was EXACTLY what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!!! :)

Comment: @lau: calculated columns will not help here: they can only access other column values of the same row. They can't be used to do aggregation.

Comment: Deleting my comment then. Thanks for the precision @a_horse_with_no_name